# How to Load two different Stores on change of the checkBox from the controller (on check and uncheck)

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.2

In my application, i have a Tree panel docked with few items like checkbox and save button

- On page load, the checkBox is selected(true), so the default store which is applied in the View is loaded
- On change of the checkBox value (false) now its false, In this case i need to load different data from the different store
- Please see in the below controller, were the "loadAllTreeItems" is on change of the checkbox,
- Now in the LoadAllTreeItems method, checkBox value is checked for the true and getStore is called to load the data
- After that when the checkbox value is false, i need to load a different store, which i could not able to figure out how to do it

**Controller**

```
 Ext.define('Srn.controller.cQuery.UnnamedQueryTabController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',  
    stores : [ 'cQuery.mainesrntreeStore'], 
    views : ['cQuery.mainesrntreeView'],
    init : function() {     
        this.control({
            'unnamedquery mainesrntree toolbar checkbox[name=srnSwitchAllTree]' : {
                change : this.loadAllTreeItems,
                afterrender : this.loadAllTreeItems
            }
    },  
    loadAllTreeItems : function(checkBox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {

        if(newValue && checkBox.checked == true) {
            checkBox.up('mainsrntree').getStore().load();

        }else{
            checkBox.up('mainelntree').getRootNode().removeAll();
```

> //TODO - How to call another store and show it in the mainsrntree

```
        }
    }
});
```

**Store 1:**

```
Ext.define('srn.store.cQery.MainsrnTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad : false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'getsrnTree,
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET'
        }
    },
    root: {
        text: 'srn Object Tree',
        id: 'treeId',
        expanded: true
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]  

});
```

**Store 2:**

```
Ext.define('srn.store.cQuery.presrnTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',   
    id:'psrnTreeStoreid',
    autoLoad : false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'getPTree',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        }
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Tree display of Object',
        id: 'pTreeid',
        expanded: true
    },    
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});
```

**View :**

```
Ext.define('srn.view.cQuery.MainsrnTreeView', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mainsrntree',
    id:'mainsrntree',
    width : '100%',
    resizable : false,
    autoHeight : true,
    maxHeight : 450,
    border : false,
    rootVisible : false,
    layout : 'fit',
    enableDD: false,
    mask: true,  
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this, chkVal = null;

         Ext.apply(me, {
             store : me.buildStore()
         });


        me.dockedItems = [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            layout : 'auto',
            dock: 'top',
            items: [{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'queryNameTextField',
                fieldLabel: 'Query Name',
                labelAlign : 'top',
                width : 150,
                enableKeyEvents : true,
                allowBlank : false,
                maxLength : 150,
                minLength : 3                   
                },{
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'Save',
                cls: Ext.isIE8 ? 'ie8' : '',
                //cls : 'ie8',
                name : 'saveButton',
                tooltip:"Save the Advanced Query <br> ",
                margin : '5 5 5 5',
                style : {
                    border : 'solid 1px black',
                    backgroundcolor : 'grey'
                }
            },{
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'Save As...',
                cls: Ext.isIE8 ? 'ie8' : '',
                //cls : 'ie8',
                name : 'saveAsButton',
                tooltip:"Save advanced query under a different name",
                margin : '5 5 5 5',
                style : {
                    border : 'solid 1px black',
                    backgroundcolor : 'grey'
                }
            }, {
                xtype : 'checkbox',
                name : 'srnSwitchAllTree',
                checked : true,
                boxLabel : 'Global Search'
            }]
        }];

        me.columns = [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            text: 'srn TREE',
            width : '100%',
            minWidth : 150,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'text'
        }];
        if (me.mask) {
            this.on('render', this.createMask, this);       
        }
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    /*
    buildPrefStore : function() {
        return Ext.create('srn.store.cQuery.psrnTreeStore',{
            id : 'mainsrnTreeStoreId'+Ext.id()
        });
    },
    */
    buildStore : function(){
        return Ext.create('srn.store.cQuery.MainsrnTreeStore',{     
            id : 'mainsrnTreeStoreId' + Ext.id()

        });     
    },
    createMask: function() {
        var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(this, {msg : "Loading..."});
        this.on('beforeload', mask.show, mask);
        this.on('load', mask.hide, mask);
        /*var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(this.getEl(), this.maskConfig);    
        this.on('beforeload', mask.show, mask);
        this.on('load', mask.hide, mask);**/
    }
});
```

Comment: Do any one have answers for my doubt ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no answer regarding this. :( I can suggest to ask someone who is active in these tags through email (that is, if they have provided it).

Comment: I found the answer myself, i used setExtraparam to pass the parameter to the java controller and get the extra method what i required.

Comment: I see. But you have placed bounty on this question and it will be lost after several days. :(

Comment: If there is no answer given also, bounty points will be lost ?, if that the case the appl, design is bad.

Comment: Yes :/ That's what it says in Help section.

Answer (score 1):

First calling buildStore  is not a good practice. give your store id directly or use alias of your store if you want to create a new instance of your store. (alias: 'store.psrnTreeStore' then use type and psrnTreeStore). using Ext.create is not recommend in your component construction logic. It will eventually get you in trouble.

in controller.loadAllTreeItems you may want to change url of store's proxy instead of extraparams which would be more suitable for REST architecture.

Another solution to your problem(recommended) is to use a container with card layout for separate trees and just switch between trees. Using setActiveItem methods which is a much more efficent alternative in terms of performance but memory and also it is more maintainable,readable.